# Iframe cannot get its parent's URL parameter

Tags: php, html, iframe, url-parameters

The parent URL looks like this

`http://exampledomain.com/~somename/index.php/en/pagename.html?parameter1=1`

In above page, there is an iframe which stored on same domain. URL of iframe looks like this

`http://exampledomain.com/~somename/form/index1.php`

Inside index1.php, there is javascript code to get its parent's url parameter. Like this

```
var $_GET=parent.get;
var voucher=0;
if ($_GET['parameter1']==1) voucher=1;
```

Console window always return error at `if` line

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parameter1' of undefined

Please advice, thank you very much.

Comment: What is `parent.get`?  That's not anything standard.

Comment: I don't know, someone wrote this code. The iframe is working fine on my localhost but not in external host.

Comment: In the parent window JS there must be a global variable named `get`, can you please post its code too if there is.

Comment: There is no global variable named get and parent. I really have no idea where they came from. :(

Answer (score 0):

there is nothing like parent.get in PHP

Use this

```
 echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

this will return the referer of the page.. Hope this wil work

Comment: Now it's return this
http://exampledomain.com/~somename/index.php/en/pagename.html?parameter1=1

So how can I get the parameter1's value?

Answer (score 0):

I just did it this way, it's not good enough but this will do.

```
var $_GET=parent.get; //I deleted this variable
var voucher=0;    
var get_voucher = "<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; ?>";
    get_voucher = get_voucher.slice(-1); //Get the last character

if (get_voucher==1) voucher=1; // This line isn't use $_GET[''] anymore.
```

Thanks you all. :)